# Armazenar tempo em campo tipo TIME maior que 838:59:59 no MySql

Tags: mysql, time

Boa tarde,

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesta questão? Estou precisando armazenar valores de tempo maior do que 838:59:59 em campo do tipo TIME no MySql. Existe alguma alternativa para o tipo TIME conseguir armazenar valor maior do que 838:59:59?

Agradeço desde já quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Você precisa gravar um campo de tempo decorrido? Por que não usa o integer/big int convertido para segundos?

Comment: Vc diz converter o formato, por exemplo 1445:45:00 para inteiro?

Comment: Eu vou esperar respostas muito boas, porque data/hora é um ponto fraco meu.

Comment: Isso: gravar 00 + (45 * 60) + (1445 * 60 * 60) = 5202000 segundos

Comment: Ah sim, valeu pela dica, vou tentar fazer algo assim, obrigado!